# Is there a way to stop an initiated function?

Tags: javascript

I have a function with a setTimeout method. I want to stop it if the user executes another function (prevent "Alert" from happening). Is that possible?

```js
function myFunction() {
    setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
}
function stopThis() {
    //how to stop myFunction()?
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to wait 3 seconds, then alert "Hello".</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Activate</button>
<button onclick="stopThis()">Stop it</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Window/clearTimeout) function

```
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
}

function myStopFunction() {
    clearTimeout(myVar);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll have to store the return value of `setTimeout` and then [clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout) it:

```
var timeout = setTimeout(..);

..

clearTimeout(timeout);
```